# Django - How to Modularize a large web Application?

Tags: django

I'm trying to figure out the best way to build a large web application, but keeping the various logical sections modularized. For example, there will be a number of different logical sections:

- Estimates
- Work Orders
- Accounting
- Contacts
- etc...

As much as possible, I want to have the code for each of these modules disconnected from all the other modules. If code from one section starts to throw errors or cause incorrect data, I don't want that to affect other modules.

My first thought is just to separate by using Django 'apps'. Each module is its own app. Then, if I build each app to be "pluggable", then the code is self sufficient. However, the problem with this approach is that the modules will likely need to access the `models` of other modules. For example, the 'Accounting' module will need access to the 'Contacts' `model`, since we want to send invoices to people in our contacts list.

I looked into having a completely separate Django project for each module, but that poses problems (I think) for user authentication. Plus, to my knowledge, multiple Django projects can't (easily) share one database.

Just wondering if there are any good ways or best practices to make logically separate 'modules' while, as much as possible, keeping the code from one module completely isolated from the rest, but still having a cohesive web application.

Comment: In almost any practical web app, you will have interdependent modules/apps. More important than avoiding that is ensuring your project is laid out logically and concerns are separated where it's both sensible and realistic; if you're using Django, use apps for this. Some will depend on each other, but as long as you're keeping functionality in logical places, this is not _necessarily_ bad (though it can be, like anything else, if your architecture has issues). It's just a side effect of actually doing work that isn't either theoretical or absurdly simple.

Comment: @kungphu That was kind of my suspicion. The various apps, while largely independent, still require at least read access to some models from other apps. I guess it's unavoidable.

Comment: Yes, it often is unavoidable; while it's good practice to minimize interdependence, the common admonition to avoid it like the plague strikes me as impractical. Plan out your apps as well as you can to the extent that your project can be implemented in such a modular way, and keep an eye out during development for misplaced functionality that should be relocated; that's all you can reasonably expect to do.